# css of ::before pseudo-element selector not being shown in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, bootstrap-4

There is a background frame, within it I want to show a **vertical video(4:5 aspect ratio)**, for which I have given a **padding-top value of 125%** to the **::before pseudo-selector**. It shows up perfectly in **every browser/OS except the Safari browser**. I googled & tried a few things but none of them worked.

Initially i thought that it must have got cached as css changes do, so hardrefreshed the page, cleared the browser history. Also, i added postion: absolute property. Nothing worked out.

```
<div class="backgroundImageClass">
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-9by16">
<iframe></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

the css is -

```
.embed-responsive-9by16::before {
display: block;
content: "";
padding-top: 125%;
}
```

I expected that ::before property would be taken. But it is not being taken. The css just doesn't show up when I inspect element it. The background image can only be seen that too only the middle part.

Comment: If you have an issue in css, please add your css to the example code. (Try using a code snippet.)

Comment: I agree with TVBZ. You should add an snipped to help us analyse the code and help you. But just to drop an idea, have you try using box-sizing: border-box. Think that, otherwise padding is adding height to your element, so a percentage unit creates a loop in the CSS logic and that might be not well managed by some browsers.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Any help would be appriciated